# Return a list of e-mails, comma separated, based on information in another column

Tags: excel, email

I am currently trying to design an efficient system for my public library for contacting participants for courses. Currently, we have a giant list of hundreds of people that we have to manually comb through to find out what courses they're interested in, their information, etc.

I am trying to use the e-mails we have on record for these hundreds of people (a column of its own), and spit them out in a comma-separated list in another cell, based on whether or not they have an "x" in another column, which represents their interest.

Ex.

```
Email - - - - - - - (Class 1) | (Class 2)
johndoe@mail.com         x    |
```

If I wanted to print out an email list to another cell for Class 1, how would you propose it be done? The desired result is something like:

"email1@mail.com", "email2@mail.com"... etc, so it can be copied and pasted easily by the others who work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make your life harder than it needs to be. Use the column filters in the table heading to show only the emails with an X for that course. Then copy and paste the visible results.

You can paste straight into an email client "To" field, without converting to a comma separated list.

Or, use Word Mail Merge, with this file as the data source, merge to email. Edit the data source settings and filter on the desired column. Then merge to email. No appending, copying or pasting at all.